# Getting Black Screen instead of Home screen behind Biometric fingerprint popup

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using biometric for fingerprint detection, User can select device credentials from fingerprint popup And for that I have used                 setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_WEAK or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)

But When I use DEVICE_CREDENTIAL here it shows me black screen behind the fingerprint popup. And Without DEVICE_CREDENTIAL It shows Home screen behind fingerprint popup. And this issue is specific for Samsung device. In other devices it shows Home screen behind it.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: any solution for this ?